# Incorrect sentence : I had been to mumbai when he came to meet me

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct?

> I had been to mumbai when he came to meet me

It was written in a book but my friend and I think it is not correct.

Comment: It is not possible to determine whether the sentence is correct or incorrect unless we understand the context in which it is written. Please use the [edit] link to tell us what the writer is trying to express. What is the name of the book? (One thing is definitely incorrect: in English, we capitalize all proper and place names such as _Mumbai._)

Comment: Why do you and your friend think it's incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Your example

> I *had been* **to** Mumbai when he *came* to meet me.
>   *I had travelled to Mumbai when he came to se me.*

is correct. Possibly better might be

> I *had been* **in** Mumbai when he *came* to meet me.

The *past perfect* "**had been**" places your *location* *before* the *simple past* "**came**"